# How to port the Linux system to a new hardware architecture?

Tags: linux

I mean that I have developed a new but simple RISC CPU based on FPGA and construct a computer hardware system.

Now I need to port the Linux to the hardware system.
I have no clear sense of the process. What to do first and then?

Thanks.

Comment: 1) Write C compiler 2) Compile kernel 3) ??? 4) Profit! ... Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Write C compiler back end.
2. Write task dispatcher.
3. Write memory allocator.
4. Write IO subsystem.
5. Write the network stack.
6. Write hardware drivers, mass storage, serial, dma and etc.
7. Cross compile kernel.
8. Fix all the missing pieces.
9. Compile utilities.
10. Now go back to 1. and fix everything to the way you should have done it in the first place if you knew then what you knew now.

At least that's the way we did it.  Usually a three man team.  One did the task manager and memory allocator, one did the IO routines, and one did all the UI and utility stuff.  With substantial overlap.

Of course if your initials are LT and the compiler is already written and you crowd source the rest of it, that makes it easier.

Comment: Thanks very much.Frankly, that sounds terrible for me to do something about the compiler. I have never do any functional utility about compiler even though I know that I can not avoid facing compiler. That is the most different part for me i think.

Comment: It is not something I would want to do if I wasn't being paid for it. Check out http://llvm.org supposed to be easier.  I haven't tried it.

Comment: Thanks. It is my dream to understand the computer system from circuit to top level. I think I will do my best maybe I will never be successful in the end.